# jQuery input prob disable false by clicking the input

Tags: jquery, input, click

i want by clicking on an input element, that the prop, "disabled" is getting false, but this is not working.

to set all input on .ready to "disabled" -> true is working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").prop("disabled", true); // this is working
});

$("input").click(function() { 
 $(this).prop("disabled", false); // this is not working
});
</script>
```

---

**SOLUTION / EDIT (sorry I am not allowed to use the answer-button on my own question):**

I found a better solution.
Using "readonly" instead of "disabled" does the job.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

   $("input").prop("readonly", true);      

   $("input").click(function() { 
        $(this).prop("readonly", false); 
    });

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your logic is reverted. `Disabled=true` means actually that element is disabled (not clickable).  Try this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(this).removeProp("disabled");      

   $("input").click(function() { 
        $("input").prop("disabled", "disabled"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: @Itay seems like you're right , but how will it work , inputs will not launch `click` events if they're in `disabled` state

Comment: @Mike have a look at my answer now

Comment: Maybe there's still a way with custom variables saying that it's disabled and preventDefault if it's "disabled". P.S - It looks like a really odd behavior

Comment: Yep, but at least it'll work :) I think the whole requirement for this behavior should be reconsidered by the OP

Comment: @Chrniv its working - but its the other way round. 1) disabled 2) click 3) not disabled