# jQuery code does not work on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, click

this code is working fine on desktop browsers, but on iOS (iPhone 5 / iOS 7) it doesn't.
By clicking outside the clicked input, the clicked input does not get readonly->true again. **UPDATED CODE:**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("input").prop("readonly", true);

    $('input').bind('click', function () {
        $(this).prop("readonly", false);
    });

    $('input').bind('blur', function () {
        $(this).prop("readonly", true);  
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HxgXA/

Comment: @TusharGupta your code is also working - but only for Desktop browsers - on iOS = no changes - still not working

Comment: use inside $(function () {        });

Comment: @gobi i test it inside the function - it does also not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use this for adding readonly attribute,

To add,

```
$("input").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

To remove,

```
$("input").removeAttr("readonly");
```

This is the correct method

Comment: i updated my code. but your answer is not a solution on iOS devices. since jquery 1.6+ i think you should use .prop instead of .attr

Comment: Replace bind function with on. Try $('input').on('click', function () {});

Comment: thanks for your input - but changing "bind" to "on" does not work on iOS